# Можно ли получать константы без вызова класса?

Tags: java

Допустим есть строка

```
String test = "example";
```

и нужно чтобы её можно было использовать как строку в любом классе в таком виде:

```
String test2 = test + "";
```

(это два разных класса)

Answer (score 4):

Для вызова статических переменных, без имени класса, нужно использовать `import static`.

```
import static packet.Class.*
```

Это импортнет все статические публичные свойства.
А это:

```
import static packet.Class.VAR;
```

Импортнет только свойство `VAR`, которое можно будет использовать без указания названия класса.

Comment: Только не нужно, а можно. Вообще раньше была мода хранить константы в интерфейсах, но сейчас это вроде не комильфо. Предлагается вариант с проперти файлами.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, толку то от этого? Интерфейс нужно будет наследовать - это банально и абстракция подойдет и любой другой класс. А тут конкретно импорт статики. Так, что нужно, чтобы не вызывать по классу или наследованию.

Comment: Что значит " Интерфейс нужно будет наследовать"?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець То и значит, что без наследования, вы не сможете вытащить переменную без обращения к имени интерфейса. `Interface.VAR`. `static import` дает возможность без наследования импортнуть статику и использовать ее без указания названия класса при чем, они могут лежать в разных пространствах, пакетах и иметь разные инструкции или нативные реализации. нежели ваш интерфейс, который надо будет и импортнуть и наследовать.

Comment: @And про наследование что-то не то написали, оно не нужно, чтобы получить переменную из интерфейса, импорта достаточно.

Comment: @keekkenen, да не нужно если будете обращаться по имени интерфейса. Читайте внимательно.